# Identify answers which might yet get accepted

Tags: feature-request, answers, search, profile-page, accepted-answer

Sometimes I'd like to see

- questions without an accepted answer
- for which I wrote an answer

This might be useful to remind users to accept an answer, or to keep track of questions where additional information might be required in order to make an answer acceptable even if there were no comments directly on the answer I wrote.

The **Answers section** in my profile distinguishes between answers which have been accepted and those which have not, but for the latter does not show whether another answer has been accepted for the same question.

And the **search** doesn't seem able to provide that information: it searches *either* for questions *or* for answers, but the `hasaccepted:0` refers to the question whereas the `user:me` should refer to the answer, so it seems they'll never match at the same time.

Comment: If you're just going to use this to bug users to accept your answer then I can't agree at all... especially as, however benign _you_ intend to be, others might not be so nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with your assertion that:

> The Answers section in my profile distinguishes between answers which have been accepted and those which have not, but for the latter does not show whether another answer has been accepted for the same question.

I can't see what the point of this suggestion/[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) would be; is it to 'remind' or 'prompt' those asking questions (without a yet-accepted answer)? Or is for you to keep track of your unaccepted answers, for a sort of visual feedback?

Further, as a potential for a... answers-for-review list, while I agree it could be potentially useful, I'm not convinced that it merits the work for the team; plus is it that hard to go through your answers with low votes (often, if not always, a better sign that something might be required to improve your answer) and review them anyway?

Either way it's not a feature request I could support, or vote for, since the first possibility seems potentially open to abuse (and I've seen far too many 'you have a low accept rate, fix that first...' comments over the past few months to trust that it *wouldn't* be abused (by *some*) in such a manner.

And, as a user, I'm not sure what it adds to my summary screen, other than cluttering the UI further.

Comment: “Keep track of unaccepted answers“: Yes, differentiating between the alternatives there. “low-vote answers”: While I agree that they might merit addition, there is little point when someone else had a better answer which got accepted, and also little point when the answer was given seconds ago. So I'm interested in answers I gave a while back but where the original poster might still be interested in additional details. I can understand yoiur concern for abuse, though, so I'll understand if you reject this request.