# Search for not-accepted questions within my answers

Tags: support, search

I want to find all my answers to questions that don't have accepted answers. How do I do that?

[Search inside my own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140279/search-inside-my-own-answers) gets part of the way to what I need - until the query tries to focus on questions without accepted answers, that is.

A search for [user:me is:answer hasaccepted:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20is:answer%20hasaccepted:no) shows my own *questions*, it doesn't stay confined to my answers. (That's got to be a bug, right?)

A search for [user:me is:answer isaccepted:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1677912%20is:answer%20isaccepted:no) returns a list of my answers (good) that weren't accepted (still ok), but includes answers from questions that do have some other accepted answer (boo!).

Comment: Yes, definitely a bug.

Comment: @Mogsdad, I agree this would be useful, especially for people who do a lot of cleanup answering neglected questions (for which I proposed a gold badge: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268 ): often they are by newbie askers etc. and some poking is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say this was a bug, exactly. `user:me is:answer hasaccepted:no` is self-contradictory.  A post can't both *be* an answer and *have* an answer (From the DB perspective, at least).

It might be nice if the search page gave you a warning, rather than just returning results that you don't want. But, accounting for all the possible contradictory search terms could be a low value-to-cost task.

`user:me is:answer isaccepted:no` works as it should.

What you want is more complex, and requires searching *questions* for one set of criteria while searching *answers* for a different criteria. For example, this would require two passes through [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!Sri2WoZktB9KDB96HE&site=stackoverflow).

To get this feature, you should make a *Feature Request*.  Except that there already seems to be one: ["Identify answers which might yet get accepted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139172/148310).  You could support/upvote that post, too.

---

**For immediate satisfaction**, you can use the *Data Explorer* (SEDE).  Just beware that the data is not live and can be up to a month old.

You can use my **["My answers to questions that have no accepted answer" query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111474/my-answers-to-questions-that-have-no-accepted-answer)** until such time as this feature is rolled into the search page.

For example, [SEDE currently shows that you have 59 answers to questions with no accepted answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111474/my-answers-to-questions-that-have-no-accepted-answer?UserId=1677912).